# Godbolt CMake with MSVC?

Tags: c++, cmake, godbolt

Does godbolt Cmake work with msvc? If so, can you get the cmake template working for me? https://godbolt.org/z/9j6Md7bGc

A naïve attempt, results in msvc is trying to compile the CMakeLists.txt

```
example.cpp
<source>(1): error C2065: 'shapes': undeclared identifier
<source>(1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
<source>(3): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'cmake_minimum_required'
Compiler returned: 2
```

Comment: Godbolt doesn't consume CMakeLists.txt files.

Comment: @arrowd it does for gcc and clang. There's even a template https://godbolt.org/z/9MKjcjM3M